# Are questions about writers on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, off-topic

The [What was the daily routine of Charles Bukowski like during his years at the Post Office?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/49744/11428) is closed for being about writers, not writing. However, according to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there is no explicitly criteria saying that questions about writers are off-topic or not.

So (why) would this kind of question be off-topic? I see that sometimes it's helpful to analyze a writing style. And in any case, we should add this to the help page.

Comment: If it was a question along the lines of "How does this quote from Charles Bukowski describing his daily life in regards to his writing relate to other successful authors?" or something else that focuses on the things that the help center mentions such as "planning and organizing, research techniques" it might be rewritten to be on-topic. But right now it reads like "give me a biography of this person" or "how was daily life in this time period", which is not about Writing and sounds more like Literature or History. As Cyn is mostly inactive it's unlikely that the help center will be changed.

Comment: The question is about the sleeping, betting and drinking habits of an author and not about his writing style.

Comment: Still sounds like a closer fit to Literature.SE than here.  (They may even have some mods)

Comment: @April--Un-SlanderMonica-- what is the status of this site? All the mods have resigned except one?

Comment: After Monica was kicked [a CVn](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2229/23159) and [Neil Fein](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2230/23159) resigned. Cyn is [taking a personal leave of absence](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2243/23159) and is inactive. Nobody is left and the company is leaving the site to rot. Most long-time regulars switched to [codidact](https://writing.codidact.com/). Some of us occasionally check Writing.SE but basically nobody posts or moderates the site like before anymore.